# Get or set printer user language(English, Spanish etc) for Zebra printer with socket connection

Tags: java, sockets, zebra-printers, network-printers

How can I get or set printer user language(English, Spanish etc) for Zebra using socket connection?
We have one use case where printer GUI language set to Spanish so the response/output of print jobs coming in Spanish language, we want response in English always because currently our response parsers can handle English language only.

I am expecting Zebra print job response in English not in Spanish.

Comment: Why the Java tag? Are you using some Java library for PJL?

Comment: Yes Java Socket connection, I updated question, its not PJL but Zebra printer specific commands we are sending.

Comment: just to better understand, what is the response you're getting from the printer?